# Issues with my timeout script

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm running a script that will destroy a user's session after a certain amount of inactive time.  However, it's not running correctly.  Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
    require("../includes/header.php");
    $expire = time();
    echo $expire ."<br>";

    if(!isset($_SESSION["expire"]) < ($expire + 30)){
        setcookie("User", $_SESSION["user"], 30);
        echo "Welcome " .$_SESSION["user"];
        $_SESSION["expire"] = $expire;
    }
    elseif($_SESSION["expire"] > ($expire + 30)){
        unset($_COOKIE["User"]);
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: logged_out.php");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$expire` will *always* equal `$_SESSION["expire"]` because you set `$_SESSION["expire"]` equal to `$expire` at the top of the page and never change their values.

Set `$_SESSION["expire"]` *after* you validate the user. Also, your logic seems to be incorrect:

```
<?php
    require("../includes/header.php");
    $now     = time();
    $expires = $_SESSION["expire"]  + 30;

    if(!isset($_SESSION["expire"]) || $expires > $now){
        setcookie("User", $_SESSION["user"], 30);
        echo "Welcome " .$_SESSION["user"];
        $_SESSION["expire"] = $now;
    }
    else {
        unset($_COOKIE["User"]);
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: logged_out.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but even when I do exactly the way you showed me, it's still not timing out.  Any idea why it would still not be working correctly?

Comment: Awesome.  The only thing is that "expire" is not indexed when the session variable is called, but I can work that out.  Thank you.